# How to change email settings on iPad so as not to show images by default

Tags: ipad, email, graphics

My friend has an iPad.  I have never used an iPad, but am trying to help her set things up better -- so it's clearly a case of the blind leading the blind.

In my own email (a gmail account, which I read in thunderbird), if I open a message with images, the images are not shown as images -- there's a placeholder where each image would be.

I would like to set things up that way on my friend's iPad.

How do I do that?  She reads both yahoo mail and Exchange on her iPad.

Please make your instructions detailed, clear and idiot-proof -- thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Settings.app and then go to **Mail, Contacts, Calendars.**

Scroll down the to **Mail** section...

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: You lost me already on the first sentence.  But that part, at least, I was able to google.  Once I got into the settings, your instructions worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not truly idiot-proof, as this is from an iPhone not an iPad, but the option is the same, even though the layout is slightly different...

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar... switch off 'Load remote Images'

[image]